# Excel conditional count

Tags: excel

Maybe this was asked before, but i cant describe it in few tags/words.

I am newbie with excel.

How can i countif cells in column on condition other than simple comparison?
For example "count cell if it contains data with point to other cell that is equal to something", without additional temp columns ofc and vba.

Related question: Would it be possible to set logic function during sum in range, with return added value on given cell ? For example if cell contains 5 add 9 to total sum otherwise -3.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `countif` function can also use formulae reference such as less than, greater than, so on.. Please refer to Excel Help (F1).

Examples:

`=COUNTIF(C4:C26,A1)`

the above code means that it will count the range for cells in C4:C26 which is "equal to" the value in cell A1

`=COUNTIF(C4:C26,"<0.2")`

the above code means that it will count the range for values which are less than 0.20

`=COUNTIF(C4:C26,"<"&A1)`

the above code means that it will count the range for values less than the value in cell A1.

With regards to your next question, you can use a simple `if` function to this with combination to the `countif` function such that:

`=if(countif(A1:A5,5)>=1,sum(A1:A5)+9,sum(A1:A5)-3)`

Cheers.